# Display free shipping if specific sku magento on product page

Tags: magento-1.8, sku, free-shipping

I need to display a "Free Shipping" line of text below the price on the product page if the SKU starts with certain characters -- how do I got about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the product sku to a vaiable and then you can check for the certain characters you are targetting.

```
if (strpos($_product->getSku(),'yourSKUpattern') !== false):
echo 'free shipping message';
endif;
```

Updated my answer just put in your pattern to check for and this should work

Comment: Could you be more specific on how to "assign a product sku to a variable"?

Comment: Sorry I updated my answer to skip variable assignment, you can get product sku using $_product->getSku(), using that directly in the if to check product sku

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Working flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear enjoy

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:- Please create Attribute at admin panel Go to >>Catalog >> Manage Attributes and click on Add New Attribute and create attribute. Input text filed 'Attribute Code", "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" Please select Yes/No option, and save attribute.

Step 2:- Go to >>Catalog >> Manage Attributes Set and drag & drop created attribute for General folder, After that select which product page you want to display "Free Shipping" Go to Manage Product and select product.

Step3:- Go to magento website root directory app\design\frontend\MyPackage\MyTheme\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

Edit and add this code where you want to display on front-end product page.

Add your attribute code and replace the code "getFreeShippingProduct"`

```
<?php if ($_product->getFreeShippingProduct()):?>
<div class="free-shipping-product">
<div class="std"><?php echo $this->__('Free Shipping') ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```